# Reverse Proxy for Django App 404 Not Found

Tags: django, apache, server, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide to try show this url `www.mycompany.com/testblog` instead of `www.mycompany.com:8000/testblog`

These are my current config files setup inside my website.comssl.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com
Redirect permanent / https://website.com/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com
SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/website.com.cer 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/website.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/website.com/SSLCert/SSLIntermediateCertificate.cer

ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /testblog https://website.com:8000/testblog
    ProxyPassReverse /testblog https://website.com:8000/testblog
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I run my server and try to access the URL `www.mycompany.com/testblog` I get a 404 Not Found error

Comment: Add log files in your 443 VirtualHost (different from the logs for your :80).  Look at the error log.  If it does not help, increate your LogLevel.  It will show you exactly what the proxy is trying to do.

Comment: Did you try setting SSLProxyEngine On? https://serverfault.com/questions/964454/how-can-i-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-https

Comment: Hi! Yes I have added that and sadly still not had success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you load proxy module

**On Centos/RedHat**

```
$> grep -R "mod_proxy" /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/
.....
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
.....
```

**On Ubuntu**

```
$> a2enmod proxy
$> a2enmod proxy_http
```

Answer (score 0):

> ProxyPass /testblog https://website.com:8000/testblog
>
> ProxyPassReverse /testblog https://website.com:8000/testblog

This is very uncommon to do for two reasons:

- Normally you reverse proxy stuff that's not available via public domain name. Often it runs on the same machine or on another machine in the same network. In this case, use the IP instead (127.0.0.1 for the local machine or the IP shown in `ip addr` command on the other machine)
- You're using `https:` but backend services are normally not SSL protected. Also port 8000 is very uncommon for SSL.

In other words, are you sure you want this and not `ProxyPass /testblog http://127.0.0.1:8000/testblog`

Comment: Thanks for your response. My aim is to make it so that users of the site can access `website.com/testblog` instead of currently needing to do `website.com:8000/testblog` in the URL. I agree port 8000 is uncommon and will be changed.